# What causes "duplicate entry" warnings when JAR'ing with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jar

I am `jar`ing my Java Swing application which also uses `joda.time`, `apache.commons` and a few other external `jar`s.

The output `jar` runs, however, Eclipse did report some warnings while producing the `jar` via Export > Java > Runnable Jar.  I am choosing the "repackage" option for dealing with the external `jar`s.  Here's the top of the listing of about 146 lines of warnings.

```
  JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.

  Details:
  duplicate entry: allclasses-frame.html
  duplicate entry: allclasses-frame.html
  duplicate entry: allclasses-noframe.html
  duplicate entry: allclasses-noframe.html
  duplicate entry: constant-values.html
  duplicate entry: constant-values.html
  duplicate entry: deprecated-list.html
  duplicate entry: deprecated-list.html
  duplicate entry: help-doc.html
  duplicate entry: help-doc.html
  duplicate entry: index-all.html
  duplicate entry: index-all.html
  duplicate entry: index.html
  duplicate entry: index.html
  duplicate entry: overview-frame.html
  duplicate entry: overview-frame.html
  duplicate entry: overview-summary.html
  duplicate entry: overview-summary.html
  duplicate entry: overview-tree.html
  duplicate entry: overview-tree.html
  duplicate entry: package-list
  duplicate entry: package-list
  duplicate entry: resources/inherit.gif
  duplicate entry: resources/inherit.gif
```

As this is a Swing application for the desktop, warnings about `html` and `css` (not shown) are quite unexpected.  Advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like the jar files include Javadocs. The duplicate entries will somehow clobber that. However, unless you need the Javadocs, you don't need to care. Try to get jar files without sources or docs, though.

Also, Eclipse has an option to include dependency jars as jars (rather than throwing all their contents together). You can try that, too.

Comment: Packing dependency jars into the jar (rather than packing classes into the jar) resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had my main method in `XXX.java` and moved it to `YYY.java`, so my run configuration was still set up to use `XXX` as the main entry point. At the bottom of all the `duplicate entry: blahblahblah` messages, there was one that said something like `unable to locate main class`. So I just changed my run configuration and all the errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by clicking "Package required libraries into generated JAR" in the Runnable JAR Specification of the Runnable JAR File Export dialog, instead of the default "Extract required libraries into the generated JAR".

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

Comment: Yes, it seems that the "jar in jar" solution gets rid of the warning. It's too bad the Eclipse dialogs are a little cryptic. The alternative is probably "class into jar" which exposes identifiers that provoke warnings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true.

The thing is that you are exporting to a **jar file**, extracting classes from referenced libraries(Jar library that you uses).

And, when **eclipse** extracts every thing contented in the jar files overwrite the different objects with the same name and path.

I've got the same problem, and i'm looking for a solution, because you can 'package' the jars into the jar but it's a slower runable solution.

Luck