# Eclipse-JAR creation failed "Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for", " Exported with compile warnings" and "duplicate entry"

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I download (pull) an update code of my project from bitbucket and then when I try to export a Runnable JAR File, I got the following errors. I try to solve my problem based on these pages [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378074/duplicate-entry-error-when-exporting-java-project-to-jar-with-eclipse) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108124/what-causes-duplicate-entry-warnings-when-jaring-with-eclipse) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300815/eclipse-jar-creation-failed-class-files-on-classpath-not-found-or-not-accessi). But, I could not find any solution.

I want to run my code on server so  How can I solve this problem?

I do not know how can I find duplication of the LICENSE.txt file  and other duplication files.

```
JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/definedObjTypes/TypePosting.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/input/ConvertTypeIndexToSequence.java
Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for: 'Indexing/src/input/TestInput.java'
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/input/MainInput.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/logicLayer/TreapMain.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/logicLayer/TestQueryProcess.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/logicLayer/EntityIndex.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/logicLayer/WaveletTreeMain.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/logicLayer/QueryProcess.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/logicLayer/ReCreatePostingList.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/logicLayer/Main.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/logicLayer/TestSearchResult.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/waveletTree/WaveletTreeUtilities.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/waveletTree/WaveletTreeSeq.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/waveletTree/Mapper.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/waveletTree/Main.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/waveletTree/WaveletTree.java
Exported with compile warnings: Indexing/src/waveletTree/WTNode.java
duplicate entry: about.html
duplicate entry: about.html
duplicate entry: plugin.properties
duplicate entry: plugin.properties
```

When I chose *package required libraries into generated JAR* instead of *Extract required libraries into generated JAR* all duplicate entry errors are disappeared but I still have other errors.

Comment: I can't help you with that. But you may should consider some build tools like Maven, Ant etc. It is not that hard to set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka! I’ve got it.

You (might) have a corrupt file in your repository. You need to check the “type declaration” the part of your TestInput.java file that reads:

```
import java.[blah]

public class MyJavaClass
{
// class code
```

and make sure that java file doesn’t have either a missing or malformed type declaration:

```
import java.[blah]

// I accidentally deleted my type declaration here
{
// class code
```

If you do this, you won’t be able to export anything. Eclipse is perhaps looking for files with type declarations in them to know what to compile. Deleting this, but leaving the filename named the way it is, and situated in a source folder, confuses Eclipse.